I'm trying to convert a .txt file to a .pdf file, but I'm facing this problem
def txttopdf(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        txt = request.FILES['txt']
        pdf = fpdf.FPDF()
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
        pdf.cell(200, 10, txt.read().decode('utf-8'), 0, 1)
        return HttpResponse(pdf.output(dest='S'), content_type='application/pdf')
    return render(request, 'txttopdf.html')

I create the pdf file but I cannot view its content.
I'm trying to convert a .txt file to a .pdf file, but I'm facing this problem.

What do you mean by "cannot view its content"?  What do you get?

example

Have you tried sending it as an attachment with a file name?

specify the imports.  what is fpdf ?

fpdf is probably http://www.fpdf.org/

Are you doing POST, or GET?  If you just visit that URL with your browser it's GET, and it skips to return render(...). Does txttopdf.html have an appropriate submit button and form to do the POST? CSRF Token?
